# Reading and writing data through a pipe

Tags: c, fork, pipe

I have created two processes using fork(). The child process is producing and writing continuously a variable amount of data (array char) to the pipe. The parent process reads from the pipe and prints the received data to stdout.

The code is very simple:

```
switch (fork()) {
  case -1: 
    exit (1);
    break;
  case 0:
    close(fd[0]);
    generate_data(fd[1]);
    break;
  default:
    close(fd[1]);
    while(1) {
        n = read(fd[0], readbuffer, sizeof(readbuffer));
        readbuffer[n] = 0;
        if (n > 0)
            printf ("read: %s\n", readbuffer);            
        else
            exit(1);
    }   
   break;
}
```

Where `generate_data(int)` iterates over a list, writing each element (string) to the file descriptor given as argument (the write end of the pipe in this case):

```
void generate_data(int fd) 
{
   node_t node* = list;
   while (node != NULL) {
     write(fd, node->data, strlen(node->data)+1);
     node = node->next();
   }

}
```

The problem here is that the output is always unpredictable: the child process writes data to the pipe when the other process is processing the last `read`, so when it calls to read again the rest of the data is not there anymore.

According to `man 2 pipe`, this shouldn't be happening:

> Data written to the write end of the pipe is buffered by the 
>   kernel until it is read from the read end of the pipe.

Taking a list of 10 elements, some output examples:

Example 1:

```
read: element_4
read: element_8
read: element_9
```

Example 2:

```
read: element_7
read: element_8
read: element_9
read: element_10
```

Example 3:

```
read: element_2
read: element_8
```

Anyone has any idea what's happening here?

Comment: Not without the code showing the writing, and maybe some sample output.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Minor nitpick: read() does not read null-terminated strings. your %s format expects a nul terminated string. Maybe you should add "readbuffer[n] = 0;" after the read, given enough space.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I've just edited the question with some more information.

Comment: Read my answer carefully -- it explains exactly what the problem is, and your code above confirms it. `generate_data` is sending multiple 0-terminated strings over the pipe; `printf` is just printing the first one. Either replace the zeroes with newlines in `generate_data`, or parse them out in your reading code. But the key thing is that `printf` is ignoring most of what you give to it, because it stops printing at the first 0 byte.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You call `read` and capture the return value, but then you largely ignore it; it's telling you how many valid bytes are in `readbuffer`, but you're treating `readbuffer` as if it contains  a zero-terminated string, which it does not necessarily. In fact, a single `read` may be giving you *multiple* zero-terminated strings, if your data-writing process is sending `0` bytes through the pipe; using `printf` means you're ignoring the second and subsequent ones. At the very least, you'll need to use `fwrite` to write the specific, correct number of bytes to stdout, although I suspect what you'll actually need to do is replace those zeroes with newlines first. It might be a better idea to modify `generate_data` to send newlines instead of zeroes.

Comment: In particular, what is likely happening is that two or more strings are arriving in the one `read()` call - but the code only prints the *first* string and ignores the rest, so it appears as though they have been lost.

Comment: Oooh, yeah, I bet that's it. The write process is sending `0` bytes through the pipe; they are in the middle of the data!

Comment: @Ernest, you're right. I forgot `readbuffer[n] = 0` just after the read. Sorry. But anyway, the problem is still there.

Comment: See my edited answer -- there's a subtlety that I originally missed.

Comment: @Ernest, after some fun with gdb I can confirm your theory :-) Thanks so much! That was getting me crazy.

Answer (score 0):

Read does not stop at the nul character, you might read two "messages" in one read() call. So your reader has to check if there is more data after the first 0 (but within the n bytes read), and save it. A next read call should append its data to this leftover. A special case is when there is a leftover, but not yet a complete message in the buffer.